# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'aaa' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error in the title when trying to do a simple search from a textbox through an `SqlDataSource` output to a gridview. If I search for **123** it returns the record with ID 123, as it should. If I search for **aaa** it returns the error. Anyone have any idea why??? The database looks like so:

```
id       int           (primary key / identity)
struser  nvarchar(50)
```

The SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT id, struser 
FROM ticket 
WHERE (id = @id) OR (struser = @struser)
```

Comment: Because "aaa" can't be compared with an integer...if you want to implement kind of "full text search" with integers too then you may need to pass only one parameter and to convert everything to string for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT id, struser 
FROM ticket 
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR,id) = @id ) OR (struser = @struser)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement, below assumes you have no id value of `-1`:

```
SELECT id, struser FROM ticket WHERE (id = CASE ISNUMERIC(@id) WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(int,@id) ELSE -1 END) OR (struser = @struser)
```

Comment: No, `CASE ISNUMERIC(@id)` returns a bit value so `WHEN 1` checks for 'true'. Also the `CONVERT` is vital, what if user entered `100.5`?

Answer (score 0):

try casting it to `varchar` but *I think* it will not use index anymore.

```
WHERE (CAST(id AS VARCHAR(20)) = @id)
```

Comment: Just checked and you're right this doesn't use an index (at least on the table I tried it on).